# useEffect dependencies not re-rendering component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to re-render a component using useEffect and passing dependencies, but it isn't working. I'm quite new to react hooks so I think I might not be passing the correct dependency. I'm fetching some info and updating the state, however, when I passed the dependencies the re-render cycle does not happen.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Loader from "../UI/loader/loader";

import axios from "axios";
import "./surveybox.css";

interface surveryAnswer {
  id: number;
  answers: string[];
}

const SurveyBox: React.FC = () => {
  const [surveyUserAnswers, setSurveyUserAnswers] = useState<surveryAnswer>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [numberOfAnswers, setNumberOfAnswers] = useState<number>();

  const programmingQRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);
  const skillsQRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);
  const stateManagementQRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);
  const programmerTypeQRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${DB_URL}/users-answers.json`)
      .then((res) => {
        const fetchedAnswers = [];
        for (let item in res.data) {
          fetchedAnswers.push({
            ...res.data[item],
            id: item,
          });
        }
        setNumberOfAnswers(fetchedAnswers.length);
      })
      .catch((err) => {});
  }, [numberOfAnswers, setNumberOfAnswers]);

  const onSubmitSurvey = (e: React.FormEvent): void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading((prevLoading) => !prevLoading);
    const newAnswer = {
      id: Math.random(),
      answers: [
        programmerTypeQRef.current!.value,
        skillsQRef.current!.value,
        stateManagementQRef.current!.value,
        programmerTypeQRef.current!.value,
      ],
    };

    setSurveyUserAnswers(newAnswer);

    axios
      .post(`${DB_URL}/users-answers.json`, newAnswer)
      .then((res) => {
        setLoading((prevLoading) => !prevLoading);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading((prevLoading) => !prevLoading);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="surveybox-container">
      {loading ? (
        <div className={"loader-holder"}>
          <Loader />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <React.Fragment>
          <h2>Quick survey!</h2>
          <form action="submit" onSubmit={onSubmitSurvey}>
            <label>favorite programming framework?</label>
            <select ref={programmingQRef} name="programming">
              <option value="React">React</option>
              <option value="Vue">Vue</option>
              <option value="Angular">Angular</option>
              <option value="None of the above">None of the above</option>
            </select>
            <br></br>
            <label>what a junior developer should have?</label>
            <select ref={skillsQRef} name="skills">
              <option value="Eagerness to lear">Eagerness to learn</option>
              <option value="CS Degree">CS Degree</option>
              <option value="Commercial experience">
                Commercial experience
              </option>
              <option value="Portfolio">Portfolio</option>
            </select>
            <br></br>
            <label>Redux or Context Api?</label>
            <select ref={stateManagementQRef} name="state-management">
              <option value="Redux">Redux</option>
              <option value="Context Api">Context Api</option>
            </select>
            <br></br>
            <label>Backend, Frontend, Mobile?</label>
            <select ref={programmerTypeQRef} name="profession">
              <option value="Back-end">back-end</option>
              <option value="Front-end">front-end</option>
              <option value="mobile">mobile</option>
            </select>
            <br></br>
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
          </form>
          <p>answered by {numberOfAnswers} visitors</p>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm passing the two dependencies that are involved in the useEffect and changes but still not working.

Thank you!

Edited Solution after recommendation:

```
...
interface surveryAnswer {
  id: number;
  answers: string[];
}

const SurveyBox: React.FC = () => {
  const [surveyUserAnswers, setSurveyUserAnswers] = useState<surveryAnswer>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [numberOfAnswers, setNumberOfAnswers] = useState<number>(0);

  const programmingQRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);
  const skillsQRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);
  const stateManagementQRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);
  const programmerTypeQRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);

  const fetchAnswersFromServer = () => {
    axios
      .get(`${DB_URL}/users-answers.json`)
      .then((res) => {
        const fetchedAnswers = [];
        for (let item in res.data) {
          fetchedAnswers.push({
            ...res.data[item],
            id: item,
          });
        }
        setNumberOfAnswers(fetchedAnswers.length);
      })
      .catch((err) => {});
  };

  const onSubmitSurvey = (e: React.FormEvent): void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading((prevLoading) => !prevLoading);
    const newAnswer = {
      id: Math.random(),
      answers: [
        programmerTypeQRef.current!.value,
        skillsQRef.current!.value,
        stateManagementQRef.current!.value,
        programmerTypeQRef.current!.value,
      ],
    };

    setSurveyUserAnswers(newAnswer);

    axios
      .post(`${DB_URL}/users-answers.json`, newAnswer)
      .then((res) => {
        fetchAnswersFromServer();
        setLoading((prevLoading) => !prevLoading);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading((prevLoading) => !prevLoading);
      });
  };

  return (...
```

Comment: How did you verify the effect doesn't run? Every effect runs at least one time after mount. Also the way you set it up it will reapeatedly fetch new data as you mutate the value that triggers the effect in the effect itself.

Comment: `numberOfAnswers` doesn't appear to be a dependency as it's not referenced in the effect callback, and secondly, unconditionally calling `setNumberOfAnswers` to update the `numberOfAnswers` can likely create an infinite loop. I suspect this effect runs once on mount, updates the state and runs a second time, and updates state again to the same value and then never updates again since the state is the same value. What do you want to trigger the effect? When do you want the fetch to occur?

Comment: The useEffect() runs but it doesn't re-run. I want re fetch the data so I can update the number of users answering the survey. So I was thinking to re-render every time there is a new submission. I'm not actually sure about the logic anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably only want the HTTP call to be made once (when the component mounts), so use `[]` as the dependency list. The HTTP call doesn't depend on any other props or state, so this most likely what you want.

If you want it to run more often than that, then you'll need to decide what data changes that requires you to make the HTTP call again, and add *that* to the dependency list instead of `numberOfAnswers` or `setNumberOfAnswers`.

The problem is that your effect lists `numberOfAnswers` as a dependency, and it also updates `numberOfAnswers` when it runs. So, this is likely what's happening:

- The component mounts. `numberOfAnswers` is undefined by default.
- The effect runs for the first time.
- The HTTP request returns, say with 10 answers. It calls `setNumberOfAnswers(10)`
- The component rerenders with `numberOfAnswers=10`
- The effect runs again, because `numberOfAnswers` changed.
- The HTTP request returns, probably with the same 10 answers. It calls `setNumberOfAnswers(10)`
- The component does *not* rerender again because the value hasn't changed.

Comment: Thank you, my logic was completely off. I added a different logic and it works. You can see it in the initial question

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

`numberOfAnswers` doesn't appear to be a dependency as it's not referenced in the effect callback, and secondly, unconditionally calling `setNumberOfAnswers` to update the `numberOfAnswers` can likely create an infinite loop. I suspect this effect runs once on mount, updates the state and runs a second time, and updates state again to the same value and then never updates again since the state is the same value.

## Solution

> So I was thinking to re-render every time there is a new submission.

You can trigger the `useEffect` on the `surveyUserAnswers` being updated.

Additional suggestions:

1. No need to create an new array and push elements into it just to compute the number of answers. Use the `res.data.length` if an array, or `Object.values(res.data).length` if it's an object.
2. Don't toggle the loading state, just set to `true` when starting the asynchronous loading action, and use a `finally` block to clear the loading state regardless if the Promise resolved or rejected.

Code:

```
const SurveyBox: React.FC = () => {
  const [surveyUserAnswers, setSurveyUserAnswers] = useState<surveryAnswer>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [numberOfAnswers, setNumberOfAnswers] = useState<number>();

  const programmingQRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);
  const skillsQRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);
  const stateManagementQRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);
  const programmerTypeQRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${DB_URL}/users-answers.json`)
      .then((res) => {
        setNumberOfAnswers(res.data.length); // or Object.values(res.data).length
      })
      .catch((err) => {});
  }, [surveyUserAnswers]);

  const onSubmitSurvey = (e: React.FormEvent): void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    const newAnswer = {
      id: Math.random(),
      answers: [
        programmerTypeQRef.current!.value,
        skillsQRef.current!.value,
        stateManagementQRef.current!.value,
        programmerTypeQRef.current!.value,
      ],
    };

    setSurveyUserAnswers(newAnswer);

    axios
      .post(`${DB_URL}/users-answers.json`, newAnswer)
      .then((res) => {
        // handle any processing
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        // handle any other error processing
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  };
```

## Alternative Solution

Define `onSubmitSurvey` `async` and handle all the asynchronous logic via `await`s and completely remove the `useEffect` hook.

```
  const onSubmitSurvey = async (e: React.FormEvent): void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    const newAnswer = {
      id: Math.random(),
      answers: [
        programmerTypeQRef.current!.value,
        skillsQRef.current!.value,
        stateManagementQRef.current!.value,
        programmerTypeQRef.current!.value,
      ],
    };

    setSurveyUserAnswers(newAnswer);

    try {
      await axios.post(`${DB_URL}/users-answers.json`, newAnswer);
      const res = await axios.get(`${DB_URL}/users-answers.json`);
      setNumberOfAnswers(res.data.length); // or Object.values(res.data).length
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
      // handle any other error processing
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about this solution too. I will try and see if it works! thanks